# SQLAlchemy returning specific field but with different label in Marshmallow Schema

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, schema

I have a schema as so:

```
class ProviderClientSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int()
    user_id = fields.Int()
    first_name = fields.Str()
    last_name = fields.Str()
    email = fields.Str()
    contact_number = fields.Str()
    provider_id = fields.Int()
    location_id = fields.Int()
    location_name = fields.Str()
    created_at = fields.Str()
    active = fields.Bool(dump_only=True)
```

here is my respective query:

```
def list_clients_for_provider(provider_id: int):
    # Query the list of users who have records in the provider_users table that match the ID
    return db_session.query(User.first_name, User.last_name, User.email, User.active,
                            User.contact_number, ProviderClient.id, ProviderClient.user_id, ProviderClient.created_at,
                            ProviderClient.provider_id, ProviderClient.location_id, ProviderLocation.name) \
            .select_from(User).join(ProviderClient).join(ProviderLocation)\
            .filter(ProviderClient.provider_id == provider_id)\
            .all()
```

The current problem I have lies when trying to return the **location_name** in the schema. I am trying to populate that field with the ProviderLocation.name, but since "location_name" does not match the "name" field I get nothing back. If I change "location_name" to "name" in my schema I get back the desired value. I do not want it labeled as "name" I specifically want it labeled as "location_name" in the return. Is there any way to specify or modify my query where I can get back the ProviderLocation.name value but under the location_name label?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**:

specifying an attribute in the Schema will result in achieving a specific value with a customized label.

```
class ProviderClientSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int()
    user_id = fields.Int()
    first_name = fields.Str()
    last_name = fields.Str()
    email = fields.Str()
    contact_number = fields.Str()
    provider_id = fields.Int()
    location_id = fields.Int()
    location_name = fields.Str(attribute='name')
    created_at = fields.Str()
    active = fields.Bool(dump_only=True)
```